# Python Sendpulse Whatsapp API - array problem

Tags: python, arrays, rest, whatsapp

I would like to send the following post request to Sendpulse API and I get the error of:

> "tags should be an array".

I think my tags field is an array. what would be the reason and how to solve it?

```
def add_tag(self, contact_id, tag_name):
    url = base_url_whatsapp + "/contacts/setTag"

    payload_data = {
    "contact_id": str(contact_id),
    "tags": [
        tag_name
    ]
    } 

    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {self.access_token}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, params=payload_data)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print('Add Tag Successful')
        #print(response.json())  # If you expect a JSON response
    else:
        print('Request failed:', response.text)
```

I was expecting a successful response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use the `data` argument of `requests.post()` instead of `params`, so the payload is passed as body:

```py
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload_data)
```